# arp table contains addresses asigned to 00:00:00:00:00:00 mac address

Tags: mac-address, openwrt, arp

What mean `00:00:00:00:00:00` MAC address in arp table? On my OpenWRT router on interface connected to ISP I have seen 24 entries with this MAC address and on local network there are 7 entries. What these entries means or indicate?

Comment: I am not suire on OpenWRT, but sometimes  00:00:00:00:00:00 means 'unknown, did not [yet] reply

Comment: Those entries are created when an ARP request is sent with the information available (ie not the MAC address) and are updated with the data in the ARP response. If that response never arrives, the incomplete entry will remain that way. This behavior is OS implementation specific - some don't add incomplete entries until x retries, or the first request times out, and others add an entry when the initial request is sent.